# Box shadow with H element at the top (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to do this:

[image]

(I manually moved the H element above the line from the shadow)

I am however unable to have the H element ("What we do") at the correct position. My current code:

```
<div style="box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 2pt #0088cc;" class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="heading heading-border heading-middle-border heading-middle-border-center heading-border-lg" style="margin-top: -24px; width: 1202px; margin-left: -42px;">
                                    <h2>What we do</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tabs tabs-bottom tabs-center tabs-simple">

                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabsNavigationSimpleIcons1">
                                    <div class="center">
                                        <h4>test</h4>


                                    </div>
                                </div>



                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: what u want now in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've build your example with a fieldset. Its easy to manage, and you can style it all by yourself. I think this is the best way to achieve what you want.

```
<html>
 <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Bootstrap 3 - Fieldset</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <style type="text/css">

    body {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    }

    fieldset.whatwedo {
    padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em !important;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 2pt #0088cc;
            box-shadow: 0 0 3pt 2pt #0088cc;
    text-align: center;   

}

legend.whatwedo {
    width:inherit; /* Or auto */
    padding:0 10px; /* To give a bit of padding on the left and right */
    border-bottom:none;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

    </style>


</head>

<body>




<div class="container">


<fieldset class="whatwedo">
    <legend align="center" class="whatwedo"><h2>What we do</h2></legend>
    <div class="control-group">
        <p>What we do</p>
    </div>
</fieldset>


</div>



<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class="heading heading-border heading-middle-border heading-middle-border-center heading-border-lg" style="margin-top: -24px; margin-left: -42px;">
   <h2 class="text-center" style="background: #ffffff;width: 23%; margin-left: 40%; margin-top: 2px;">What we do</h2> 
</div>
```